# Difference between backends and databases in Openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I started learning Openldap 2.4, but I faced some concepts that I couldn’t understand well based on official administration guide. So I’m addressing those questions to the community in hope to find some good explanations.
The first question is what the difference between backbends and databases in Openldap? Also in documentation I found something very confusing, for example in the backbends section, I tried to create an ldap backend with those instructions.

database        ldap

suffix          "dc=suretecsystems,dc=com"

rootdn          "cn=slapd-ldap"

uri             ldap://localhost/ ldap://remotehost ldap://remotehost2

After altering my configuration directory, I found olcDatabase={1}ldap.ldif file created in cn=config folder, and no back-ldap module has been created.

Another question, is about multiple databases definition in Openldap server, if I created two databases (for example an hdb and mdb database). How a query from Ldap client is handled by the server? The data are fetched from the both databases defined with an specific order, or there is a way to chooses which database we want to interact with?

And finally, why in official administration guide we still find slapd.conf configuration style while it is deprecated? Is there any updated guide?

Thanks!!

Comment: I wouldn't say official administration guide promotes slapd.conf based configuration - https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html

Comment: But for examples (add backends, overlays ...etc) shown in the official guide still in slapd.conf style. And to perform any change we should modifiy slapd.conf file and run slaptest command in order to udpdate config directory. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The only thing that needs slaptest is IMO schema configuration. Everything else is being configured with ldapmodify.

Comment: I cannot agree more, but how can I create a ldap database using the example from the official guide with ldapmodify command ?

database ldap

suffix "dc=suretecsystems,dc=com"

rootdn "cn=slapd-ldap"

uri ldap://localhost/ ldap://remotehost ldap://remotehost2

Isn’t the example shown above is slapd.conf style ?!

Comment: The example from your question is indeed not LDIF style, but slapd.conf. But maybe you are just following old documentation / tutorials?

Comment: The example listed is from the lastest documentation
Please see the link https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html

Comment: I see, that is a bit confusing. Maybe because LDIF backend is the one kind of replacing slapd.conf (see it's description). Maybe Debian's tutorial is a bit clearer - https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup .

Comment: I also find Zytrax's guide to be awesome source - http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ . Sorry for not properly answering your question. In the end I am just a fellow noob :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this tutorial, I'll take a look !!

Comment: Why are you expecting a backend configuration to be created?

Comment: user207421 I'm expecting backend configuration because in official admin guide they talk about ldap backend not ldap database. I didn't get yet the differences between backend and database, if you can light me !!

Comment: Take to heart all of these "answers" as an indicator for what you will deal with OpenLDAP. Nobody will actually answer the question you asked. Documentation is inconsistent/out of date/confusing as hell. LOOONG deprecated systems are still the default examples in official documentation. I can't answer your question either because I came here seeking the same.